# Modal drag animations in react-navigation@v6

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I've recently upgraded to `react-navigation v6` for various functionality upgrades but seem to be having some difficulty understanding the recently added `presentation` prop available on stack navigators.

I'm working exclusively for IOS and what I basically want to achieve is the same drag-to-close behaviour `presentation="modal"` gives by default but without the asthetic look of the new screen being stacked on top of the previous screen.

I've made a basic example to highlight what it is I mean which will hopefully make more sense than my words.

If you set `presentation` to `modal` inside the `Routes.js` (line 56), on button click the modal will render and the user is able to drag down on the screen to close it. If however I use `presention="transparentModal"`, you lose the dragging functionality.

Is it possible to get this dragging functionality when using this presentation type?

**EDIT**
Link to minimal example: https://snack.expo.dev/BpTJ1Cu9m